# Trying to punch a hole in the white circle

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I cannot punch a hole in the white circle, even when I create a layer and hide it. What should I do?

See here:

[image]

Comment: Hi Gog65, welcome to GDSE! It would appear you have accidentally created multiple accounts? Stack Exchange does not support more than one account per user on a site. In case your accounts interact (upvoting your own posts, for example), they are liable to be deleted. Please go to our [help section](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and contact SE to have this issue fixed.

Comment: Also, my comment from you previous question still applies... You are creating a layer from the hidden background and hiding that layer, I'm not sure how you are expecting anything to change. The white circle is on Layer 1, you need to edit layer 1, forget about the other layers.

Comment: @CAI Hello! :) I have lost access to my previous account (I didn't associate an email with it), so I had to post the question again. You can delete the other account & question if you wish so.

Comment: @CAI How should I proceed to "punch the hole in the circle", as I did in the exterior?

Comment: You should just be able to make the selection like you did and with Layer 1 active hit the delete key on your keyboard. Since the artwork is on Layer 1 (it is visible with only Layer 1 active, after all) that's the only layer you need to worry about.

Comment: [Photoshop Basics](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/graphic-design-basics.html) should help you out.

Comment: @Gog65 please see this page http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to have your accounts joined.

Answer (score 1):

You need to work on the same layer as the circle, in this case. If you want to keep the circle for reference, then clone that layer and hide the original. Work on the cloned layer of the circle and use your eraser to punch a hole in it.